# Calculating Time Differences using xts in R

Tags: r, time, xts

I was wondering if there was a way to calculate time differences using the `xts` package without having to convert time values etc. if possible. I have an `xts` object with a time format given as `2010-02-15 13:35:59.123` (where the `.123` is the milliseconds).

Now, I would like to find the number of milliseconds until the end of the day (i.e. `17:00:00`). The problem however is that I basically have to do a few conversions of the data before I can do this (such as using `as.POSIXct`) and this becomes more complicated since I have to do it for several different days and possibly even different times. For this reason, I would prefer to not have to convert the "end of day time" and leave it as `17:00:00` such that in order to find the number of milliseconds between the present time and the end of day time I can just have a fairly simple operation such as `17:00:00.000 - 13:35:59.123 = ...`

Is there a simple way to do this with minimal conversions? I'm certain `xts` has a function which I don't know of but I couldn't find anything in the documentation :/

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I tried the more 'straightforward' route by trying to compute the time differences by first trying to use the function `as.POSIXct(16:00:00, format = "%H:%M:%S")` but this gives an error, and I'm honestly not sure why...

Comment: The function should be `as.POSIXct("16:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")` but `as.POSIXct()` will return the date, time and timezone. As in "2017-07-12 16:00:00 CDT"

Comment: You might look at the lubridate package, but I don't know if it handles fractional seconds.

Comment: @Kevin Ah thanks for that! Yes I looked into the lubridate package a few days ago actually, but I can't use it (at least as far as I know) since I am using `xts`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a combination of `ave()`, `.indexDate()`, and a custom function.  You didn't provide a reproducible example, so here's one using the daily data that comes with xts.

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
secsRemaining <- function(x) { end(x)-index(x) })
tdiff <- ave(x[,1], as.yearmon(index(x)), FUN = secsRemaining)
tdiff[86:92,]
#               Open
# 2007-03-28  259200
# 2007-03-29  172800
# 2007-03-30   86400
# 2007-03-31       0
# 2007-04-01 2505600
# 2007-04-02 2419200
# 2007-04-03 2332800
```

In your case, the call would use `.indexDate(x)` instead of `as.yearmon(index(x))`.

```
tdiff <- ave(x[,1], .indexDate(x), FUN = secsRemaining)
```

Also note that this call to `ave()` only works on a 1-column xts object.  Seems like a bug that it doesn't.  Also note that you have to use `FUN =` with `ave()`, since the `FUN` argument occurs after `...`.